# Convex hull and supporting hyperplanes

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonempty set and $p \in S$ be a point. A (closed) [halfspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_(geometry)) $H\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to *support $S$ at $p$* if $S \subseteq H$ and $p \in \partial H$. For each $p \in S$, let $$\mathrm{sh}_p(S):= \left\{\mbox{halfspace }H: \mbox{$H$ supports $S$ at $p$}\right\}.$$

Now, suppose the following assumptions: 1. $S$ is closed and 2. for every $p \in S$, $\mathrm{sh}_p(S)$ is nonempty.

My question is: is the following true?
$$
\mathrm{conv.hull}(S) = \bigcap_{p\in S}\bigcap_{H \in \mathrm{sh}_p(S)} H
$$

Comment: I believe it is true if we also take the closure of the convex hull. There are sets whose convex hull is not closed. However, the righthand side is an intersection of closed sets and hence must be closed.

Comment: There is a result saying that a closed convex set is equal to the intersection of all its supporting hyperplanes. Applying this to the closure of the convex hull should yield the result.

Comment: The examples of sets whose convex hull is not closed have points whose $\mathrm{sh}_p(S)$. I wonder if assuming $\mathrm{sh}_p(S)$ is never empty ensures that $\mathrm{conv}(S)$ is closed.

Comment: Sorry, what about $\textrm{sh}_p(S)$ are you referring to? Assuming $\textrm{sh}_p(S)\neq\varnothing$ would mean that basically every point of $S$ is a support point, i.e. every point is on the boundary and there are no "weird" points like those from the Bishop-Phelps theorem.

Comment: Oops, I left that out. Yes, I meant the assumption $\mathrm{sh}_p(S) \ne \emptyset$ for all $p \in S$. I know this assumption is really strong and eliminates pathologies like that you mentioned. However, I still don't know how to finish the argument. Even for the case when $|\mathrm{sh}_p(S)| =1$ for all $p \in S$, which should correspond to the strongly convex case.

Comment: I guess you can say I'm looking for the converse of the statement "Let $C$ be a closed convex set with nonempty interior, then the support points coincide with its boundary $S = \partial C$". Does every set $S$ that consists entirely of support points necessarily is the boundary of some closed convex set with nonempty interior?

Comment: It is worth noting that any interior point of a set has no supporting hyperplanes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Zim‘s comment that there is an issue with closedness, and that if you would als about the closure of the convex hull, the statement would be true. Further, the statement would also be true if S is compact.

The way it is stated now though, the statement seems to be false:

Let S be the union of the x-axis and the point (0,1). For each point in S the set of supporting halfplanes is not empty. For every point on the d-axis, it consists of the closes halfplane above the x-axis, and for the point (0,1) it consists of the halfplane below the line y=1. In particular, the right hand side of your statement is the closed strip between the x-axis and the line y=1. However, the convex hull of S does not include the line y=1.

Comment: nice counter example, thanks!

Comment: Do you know if there's a counterexample where $S$ is path connected?

Comment: Take S to be the union of the positive part of the x-axis and the segment between the origin and (0,1) (so like an L that is infinite in one direction)

Comment: Beautiful! :) What if $S$ has no boundary (boundary w.r.t the subspace topology on $S$ induced by $\mathbb{R}^2$)?

Comment: Wait nevermind, the example you gave already doesn't have boundary. I was trying to find a condition such that $S$ cannot have the "extremal point" $(0,1)$. Maybe the condition that $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is a $1$-dimensional topological manifold without boundary.